# Matlab profiler: optimoptions() is taking about the same time as lsqnonlin()

Tags: matlab, least-squares

I am running code which calls lsqnonlin() 1000 times. I profiled the code and found that optimoptions() was taking about 40% of the time. Instead, I set the opt1 = optimotpions() once and passed opt1 as an argument to the  function running lsqnonlin() and I saw performance improvement.

What is taking optimoptions() that long?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, let's take a look at what `optimoptions` function does internally:

```
open optimoptions
```

It seems like the core part of the function is represented by the following line:

```
options = optim.options.createSolverOptions(solverName, varargin{:});
```

Let's take a look at the `createSolverOptions` function too:

```
open optim.options.createSolverOptions
```

Bingo! A comment in the code reveals the reason why `optimoptions`, if called multiple times within a loop, may have a huge impact on the overall performance:

> We check to see if there is an installation of Global Optimization Toolbox here. Furthermore, we assume that these toolbox files will not be removed between calls to this function.
>
> Note that we do not perform a license check here to see if a user can create a set of Global Optimization toolbox options. To ensure the license check is correct, we have to check for license every time this function is called. This is very expensive if optimoptions is called multiple times in a tight loop.
>
> As such, we rely on the license manager to throw an error in the case where the user has a Global Optimization Toolbox installation, but no license is available.

The process of option objects creation is drastically slowed down by a license check included within the code. On the top of that, the `optimoptions` function and its subfunctions include a lot of `try-catch` blocks, `regex` extractions and transformations within `for loops`, and other nice pieces of code that are not very performance-friendly.